# create global transformation that adds method

Tags: groovy

I created that transformation

```
package org.global

import groovy.transform.CompileStatic 

import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ASTNode
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassHelper
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.MethodNode
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.Parameter

import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilePhase
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit

import org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation
import org.codehaus.groovy.transform.GroovyASTTransformation

import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.MethodCallExpression
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.VariableExpression
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ConstantExpression
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression

@CompileStatic
@GroovyASTTransformation(phase = CompilePhase.SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS)
public class SayHelloTransformation implements ASTTransformation {

    public void visit(ASTNode[] astNodes, SourceUnit sourceUnit) {

        BlockStatement statement = new BlockStatement()
        statement.addStatement( 
            new ExpressionStatement (
                new MethodCallExpression (
                    new VariableExpression("this"),
                    new ConstantExpression("println"),
                    new ArgumentListExpression(
                        new ConstantExpression("hello world")
                    )
                )
            )
        )

        MethodNode sayHelloMethod = new MethodNode(
            "sayHello", 0x0001, ClassHelper.VOID_TYPE, Parameter.EMPTY_ARRAY, 
            ClassNode.EMPTY_ARRAY, statement
        )

        sourceUnit.AST.methods.add(sayHelloMethod)
    }
}
```

I compiled it. Then I added `META-INF` folder with descriptor

```
org.global.SayHelloTransformation
```

So the overall structure looks like this

```
META-INF\
    services\
        org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation
org\
    global\
        SayHelloTransformation.class
SayHelloTransformation.groovy
```

Then I added `SomeClass.groovy` to the same folder as `SayHelloTransformation.groovy`

```
class SomeClass {
}
```

And `test.groovy` file

new SomeClass().sayHello()

But I got this exception

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: SomeClass.sayHello() is applicable for argument types: (
) values: []
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: SomeClass.sayHello() is applicable for argument types: () values
: []
    at test.run(test.groovy:2)
```

The whole structure looks like this

```
META-INF\
    services\
        org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation
org\
    global\
        SayHelloTransformation.class
SayHelloTransformation.groovy
SomeClass.class
SomeClass.groovy
test.groovy
```

Comment: Are you trying to test the transformation in the same project that the AST is defined? If you, you need to do your testing in a script loaded via `GroovyShell`, otherwise the compilation has already been done and your transform cannot be applied. Another approach is to use a secondary project for testing your AST.

Comment: Well..Yeah.  I use `groovyc` for compilation so I have all files in the same folder. Well layout as I showed in the question. I just want one working sample where transformation is used.

Comment: Then you need to compile them separately. GroovyShell or separate project. You can't run a transformation in the same compilation that is compiling your transformation.

Comment: Sorry, but I still do not get it. So basically what should be moved out - I have a folder with `META-INF` and `package` with `.class` file for the transformation. Then how to use it?

Comment: Yeah, you should use a proper build tool or an IDE. With both Maven and Gradle you can just run your tests that use the transformations. Both tools compile the tests separately, so you'll be all good. In IDE  you'll have to use some trick in the test, something like `assertScript` to compile the test later. [Here's a talk about how to do it (with example of adding field as a global AST transformation)](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/ast-transformations).